# Order by a column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two MySQL tables:

```
web_forums_threads
| tid | title     |
|=================|
| 1   | News Post |

web_forums_posts
| pid | tid | content  | date_created   | date_modified     |
|===========================================================|
| 1   | 1   | Today,.. | unix timestamp | null or timestamp |
| 2   | 1   | I agree! | unix timestamp | null or timestamp |
```

I want to `SELECT *` from `web_forums_threads`, and order by the most recent `date_created` value from `web_forums_posts` with the correct corresponding TID.

I feel as though the results I've found from Google may be incorrect for my case, because multiple rows can exist with the threads' TID.

The example that I tried (with no success):
`SELECT * FROM web_forums_threads WHERE fid = :postfid ORDER BY (SELECT date_created FROM web_forums_posts WHERE web_forum_posts.tid = web_forums_threads.tid) DESC;`

The syntax might be wrong but the concept is there. I don't want to add another column to the threads table because I'd just be storing info twice (the first post acts as the threads content).

Comment: JOIN and order by `date_created` or whatever

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the join between the two tables

```
SELECT * FROM web_forums_threads AS WFT, web_forums_posts AS WFP 
WHERE WFT.tid=WFP.tid 
ORDER BY WFP.date_created
```

It would be something like that

Comment: better post some usefull sample code (including full query)

Comment: Select * from web_forums_threads, web_forums_posts where web_forums_threads.tid = web_forums_posts.tid order by web_forums_posts.date_created

Comment: I may have been unclear in what I was asking for - this will select a different row for each specific web_forums_posts that exists with web_forums_threads' TID. I **only** need to select the information from web_forums_threads once, and order it by the `date_created` column in web_forums_posts. This will give me multiple rows with the same info from one thread. I need only to select each threads' info.

Comment: Then the query should be: 
Select web_forums_threads.tid, web_forums_threads.title from web_forums_threads, web_forums_posts where web_forums_threads.tid = web_forums_posts.tid order by web_forums_posts.date_created

Answer (score 1):

You can use rather JOIN.

```
SELECT T.tid, T.title
FROM web_forums_threads T 
JOIN web_forums_posts P ON T.tid = P.tid
WHERE fid = :postfid 
ORDER BY P.date_created;
```

Comment: I may have been unclear in what I was asking for - this will select a different row for each specific web_forums_posts that exists with web_forums_threads' TID. I **only** need to select the information from web_forums_threads once, and order it by the `date_created` column in web_forums_posts. This will give me multiple rows with the same info from one thread. I need only to select each threads' info.